# Jest error SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' when using it with Next js & babylon

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, ts-jest, babylonjs

I am building a 3d rendering app using `babylon.js` and `next.js`. When I try to write unit test for my app every other test runs successfully but the import from `babylon` core throws and `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"` error

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6lac.png)

Here is my jest config

```
import nextJest from 'next/jest.js';
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './'
});

const config = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@/(.*)': '<rootDir>/$1'
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/.next/', '<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['lcov'],
  coverageDirectory: 'test-coverage',
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 0,
      functions: 0,
      lines: 0,
      statements: 0
    }
  }
};

export default createJestConfig(config);
```

and my jest setup is

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { server } from './mocks/server';
window.beforeAll(() => server.listen());
window.afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
window.afterAll(() => server.close());
```

I was expecting the test to run smoothly